# How can I set to receive an email notification whe a user order in-app Google Play app?

Tags: in-app-purchase, google-play

I publish an app with in-app purchase on Google play, I hope to receive an email notification when a use order an item of this app.

How can I do?  I can't find any setting in both  https://play.google.com/apps/publish/v2/ and https://wallet.google.com/. Could you help me? Thanks!

And more, I can't get an email notification when a user pucrhased a paid app of mine on Google Play  too!

Comment: Any suggestions for me?

Answer (score 0):

I've gone though all the settings on the both the wallet and developer console and there isn't much in the way of email notification settings.

But one could build an application upon googles API for the developer console and that might give you access to the payment history so you could setup an notification system.